# Customize UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

how can i set backgroundimage in each cell of UITableviewController?

Answer (score 2):

Just Add the imageview in cell.

```
UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
                img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
                [img setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
                [cell addSubview:img];
                [img release];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this method:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"P_Highlight_Mem.png"]] autorelease];
```

Thanks